# Python file delimited with double tabs

Tags: python

I'm new to python and am working on a script to read from a file that is delimited by double tabs (except for the first row wich is delimited by single tabs"

I tried the following:

```
f = open('data.csv', 'rU')
source = list(csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True, delimiter='\t'))

        for row in source:
          print row
```

The thing is that csv.reader won't take a two character delimeter.  Is there a good way to make a double-tab delimeter work?

The output currently looks like this:

```
['2011-11-28 10:25:44', '', '2011-11-28 10:33:00', '', 'Showering', '']
['2011-11-28 10:34:23', '', '2011-11-28 10:43:00', '', 'Breakfast', '']
['2011-11-28 10:49:48', '', '2011-11-28 10:51:13', '', 'Grooming','']
```

There should only be three columns of data, however, it is picking up the extra empty fields because of the double tabs that separate the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much do you know about your data? Is it ever possible that an entry contains a double-tab? If not, I'd abandon the `csv` module and use the simple approach:

```
with open('data.csv') as data:
    for line in data:
        print line.strip().split('\t\t')
```

The `csv` module is nice for doing tricky things, like determining when a delimiter should split a string, and when it shouldn't because it is part of an entry. For example, say we used spaces as delimiters, and we had a row such as:

```
"this" "is" "a test"
```

We surround each entry with quotes, giving three entries. Clearly, if we use the approach of splitting on spaces, we'll get

```
['"this"', '"is"', '"a', 'test"']
```

which is not what we want. The `csv` module is useful here. But if we can guarantee that whenever a space shows up, it is a delimiter, then there's no need to use the power of the `csv` module. Just use `str.split` and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not an issue here , would you be fine with this quick and hacky solution.

```
f = open('data.csv', 'rU')
source = list(csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True, delimiter='\t'))

    for row in source:
      print row[::2]
```

row[::2] does a stride on list row for indexes that are multiples of 2. For the above mentioned output, index striding by an offset (here its 2) is one way to go!